# regarding geom_segment(aes(x=x0,y=y0,xend=x1,yend=y1)) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, there is a usage which looks like:

```
geom_segment(aes(x=x0,y=y0,xend=x1,yend=y1))
```

What does the `aes(x=x0,y=y0,xend=x1,yend=y1)` mean?

I checked the ggplot2 manual, but it does not explain these parameters in detail. Thanks.

Comment: I can see how x=x0 and y=y0 play? But I do not know how do xend=x1 and yend=y1 stand for?

Comment: A line segment has two ends. Each end needs an x and y value. For a total of four numbers per segment.

Comment: @user288609 Does Joran's comment answer your question? If not, you need to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aes` function is used to map variables (i.e. columns) in a data.frame to visual properties of the plot. A plot consists of one or more geometries, e.g. `geom_point` for points or `geom_polygon` for polygons. Each of these geometries has different properties, aka aesthetics. A simple example is the point geometry (`geom_point`). This geometry has the following aesthetics (from the man page, see ?geom_point for that):

```
Aesthetic   Default   
x           required  
y           required  
shape       16        
colour      black     
size        2             
fill        NA           
alpha       1
```

From this list we see that a point geometry has two required aesthetics: the x-coordinate of the point (`x`) and the y-coordinate of the point (`y`). Additional aesthetics have default values, but could also be coupled to a column in the dataset to make them variable. For example, linking `size` to a column in the data varies the size of the point according to that variable.

To get to your question. The segment geometry is used to draw line segments. The aesthetics required for that are a starting point for the line segment (`x` and `y`) and an ending point for the line (`xend` and `yend`). So the line:

```
aes(x=x0,y=y0,xend=x1,yend=y1)
```

says that we want ggplot to draw line segments for each row in a data.frame, where the line is draw from the coordinates (`x`,`y`) to (`xend`,`yend`). Hope this makes things more clear.